# javascript jquery function trigger solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is currently triggered by a focusout of an input element via

```
$('#wrapper').on('focusout','input[name=state]',function(){ 
    /* execute function */
});
```

The problem I am having is if someone decides to just skip that element with say a mouse click (as this input element is auto filled using the ziptastic plugin) then the function will not trigger. I tried `.on('change')` but that did not seem to work.

What would be the best way to trigger this function once input[name=state] has been filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a change event handler too:

```
$('#wrapper').on('focusout change','input[name=state]',function(){
```

And then also trigger the change event (`$('#wrapper input[name=state]').change()`) after the ziptastic plugin has been run. The change event won't fire if the value is set by `.val("something")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange`, it occurs either before or after the `onblur`.